# Written as an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Imagine the product of $20^{50}$ and $50^{20}$ written as an integer in standard form. how many zeros will be found at the end of this number?

Comment: Do you mean 20^{50} and 50^{20}?

Comment: What have you tried? A zero at the end of this product comes from a factor of $10=2\cdot 5$ in it. So, how many $10$ can you produce?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with either [tag:integer-lattices] or [tag:integer-programming] so I've retagged it. (Of course, if you can think of more appropriate tags, feel free to change the tags I've chosen.)

Answer (score 6):

HINT: $20^{50}\cdot50^{20}=\left(2\cdot10\right)^{50}\left(5\cdot10\right)^{20}=2^{50}\cdot10^{50}\cdot5^{20}\cdot10^{20}=2^{50}\cdot5^{20}\cdot10^{50+20}$. How many zeroes will you get from $10^{50+20}$? How many more from $2^{50}\cdot5^{20}$?

Comment: Actually, how many (for $2^{50} \cdot 5^{50}$)?